# Why is the empty set convex?

Tags: convex-analysis

Why is it the empty set, trivially convex? I see this results stated into a proof as something known, but I do not understand what's the idea idea behind it. How could I reason about convex combinations if the set has no elements?

Comment: Hint: What would it mean for it _not_ to be convex?

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger It would mean that the segment that joints two generic points of the set is not contained in the set itself

Comment: It would mean that there exists two points in it, $a$ and $b$, such that the line connecting $a$ and $b$ isn't contained in it. This is false, because there doesn't exist two points in it at all. (In other words, $\emptyset$ is convex because there's no counterexample to the convexity condition.)

Comment: The statement that the empy set is convex is *vacuously* true, as @Akiva pointed out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\forall$ statements are true on empty domains. The definition of convex requires that for every two points in the set the line connecting them is also in the set. In order to show that this didn't work you would need to produce a counterexample, for which there is none, because there's nothing to choose from.

Comment: How about a statement of the type "there exists ..."

Comment: More specifically: $\forall x\in\emptyset,P(x)$ is true no matter what $P(x)$ is.

Comment: Statements of existence are false on empty domains, because they require you to produce an example, for which there is none.

Comment: @BigbearZzz This is why the answer begins "For all statements," that is, statements of the form $\forall x . . .$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Oh, I misinterpreted that as "for every statement" rather than "for 'all' statements."

Comment: Sorry about the ambiguity, just corrected it.

Comment: $\forall x\in\emptyset \,\, \exists y \,\, y=x$ is one of the logically true statements which seem deliberately misleading

Comment: "For every pair of distinct points in $\emptyset$, the straightline joining them never lies in $\emptyset$" is a $\forall$ statement hence true according to your answer. But this implies $\emptyset$ is not convex.

Comment: @BalarkaSen If it implied that, it would also imply that $\{0\}$ isn't convex, but it clearly is.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Ok, remove the distinct from there.

Comment: @BalarkaSen Then you're describing a property that's only true for the empty set and false for all other sets. It might _look_ like it contradicts the definition of convex, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 9):

Here's another approach, without thinking about the formal quantifier logic of it.

The intersection of any two convex sets is convex, yes? Well, what's the intersection of two disjoint circles?

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider the definition of convexity. It says that for every pair of points in the set the line connecting the points are in the set.

Now this boils down to quantifier logic. The statement is of the form "for every x in the set ...". The quantifier logic says that such a statement is true for the empty set.

One **could** avoid this by explicitly excluding the empty set, but that would complicate things rather than simplify. For example there's a result that the intersection of two convex sets is convex which is complicated if you exclude the empty set in the definition.

Another trivial example of convex sets are single-point sets as it would imply that any two points in the set would be the same and the line segment connecting them would only be the point itself.